# In flutter, after uploading a file to firebase storage, how do I get the public URL?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I have these requirements:

1. I want to upload files to firebase storage.
2. I want to store a list of URLs to those files (in firebase firestore database).
3. I want to restrict viewing these files using storage rules.

Uploading a file to firebase storage is straightforward.

```
  var uploadTask = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref(ref)
      .putFile(
      file,
      firebase_storage.SettableMetadata(
          customMetadata: _customMetaData(ownerId, readAccess)));
  var url = await _getUrl(uploadTask);
```

Retrieving the url to access the file afterwards is trivial as well.

```
var url = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

However, this url includes a security token, which basically bypasses the security rules which I have setup. Anyone with the url which includes the token has access to the file. So... instead of retrieving the url as such, I've implemented this one:

```
var url = await _getUrl(uploadTask);
```

Where...

```
/*
 * When we retrieve the download url using getDownloadURL then this include security token
 * This makes the URL accessible for everybody, bypassing any security rule.
 * I'm assuming that by removing the token this url becomes a URL only accessible for
 * those who have access rights through the storage rules.
 */
static Future<String> _getUrl(firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot uploadTask) async {
  var url = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();
  var uri = Uri.parse(url);
  var newMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(uri.queryParameters)..removeWhere((k, v) => k == 'token');
  var newUri = uri.replace(queryParameters: newMap);
  var newUrl = newUri.toString();
  return newUrl;
}
```

The question is: is this the right approach? I'm puzzled why there wouldn't be a standard method to retrieve the url without the token. I'm also puzzled why nobody else is asking this question. So: what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming that by removing the token this url becomes a URL only accessible for those who have access rights through the storage rules.

This assumption is incorrect. The download URL is an opaque URL, and you can't meaningfully change it. Changing it the way you did leaves it non-functional.

If you only want authenticated users to have access to your file, you should **not** generate a download URL for it.

If you need to share information about the file with other users without granting public access, you can store its path instead of the download URL. Those users can then have access the file by constructing a [`Reference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference-class.html) to it and then calling [`getData`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/getData.html) or [`writeToFile`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/writeToFile.html) on that reference. Unlike access through a download URL, access through a reference is secured through your rules.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I believe on second thought I reconsider. I'm having trouble to display images or videos from firebase storage. Especially existing video libraries do not implement playing from memory. As location of video these libs accept file path or url. Anyway, that made me think about another solution: the rules that apply for storage also apply to the cloud firestore collection which holds the URLs, so I believe therefore one can only access the URL when he/she is entitled. Would you agree?

Comment: The URL could be shared with unauthenticated/unauthorized folks, and they'd still have access to the underlying file. If that is not a concern in your case, then indeed the unguessable nature of the download URLs may be enough security for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Frank van Puffelen's answer, I ended up implementing the below. Ref is the reference to your firebase storage image...

```
class FbStorageImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String ref;
  
  const FbStorageImage({Key? key, required this.ref, }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _FbStorageImageState();
  }
}

class _FbStorageImageState extends State<FbStorageImage> {
  Future<Uint8List?>? future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    future = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(widget.ref).getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Uint8List?>(
        future: future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data != null) {
              return Image.memory(snapshot.data!);
            } else {
              return Image.asset("notfound.png");
            }
          }
          return Center(child: DelayedCircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
}
```